# String Indexing and Suffix Trees

Tags: suffix-tree, string-search, suffix-array

I have to build some kind of a "string catalogue" out of large PDF documents for faster string/substring searches.

The mechanism should work like this:
A PDF scanner scans the PDF document for strings and invokes a callback-method in my catalogue to index that string.

Now, what technique should be used to build such a catalogue?
I have heard of:
- Suffix trees
- Generalized suffix trees
- Suffix arrays

I am mainly tending to the generalized suffix trees. Am I right or wrong then?
I guess "normal" suffix trees are only good for indexing a SINGLE string.

But what about suffix arrays? Are there generalized suffix arrays out there?

I found a lot of code in C/C++ for building a suffix tree out of a string, but none for building generalized suffix trees!

Comment: The generalized suffix tree can be builded by any algorithm for suffix tree. For string `s1, s2, ..., sn` construct new string as concatenation of `s1, s2, ..., sn` separated by characters `$1, $2, ...` which is not contained in the main alphabet : `S = s1$1s2$2...$n-1sn$n`

Comment: The main drawback of the suffix tree is a large amount of memory required (10n - 20n bytes, where n is the length of the text).

Comment: Thats exactly how I am doing it in the mean while. I am loading the whole content as a SINGLE string and create one tree out of it. It works, but I would like to do it the way the generalized suffix tree does it.